# Empty TfRecordDataset created

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tfrecord

Below is my code to create a TFRecord.

```
    def _int64_feature(value):
        return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


    def _bytes_feature(value):
        return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


    def create_tf_record(filename):
        writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)

        subFoldersOfImages = glob.glob(PATH)
        for subFolder in subFoldersOfImages:
            image_paths = glob.glob(subFolder + '/*.jpg')

            for path in image_paths:
                img = cv2.imread(path)
                height = img.shape[0]
                width = img.shape[1]
                depth = img.shape[2]

                label = 1
                feature = {'label': _int64_feature(label),
                           'image': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()),
                           'height': _int64_feature(height),
                           'width': _int64_feature(width),
                           'depth': _int64_feature(depth)
                           }
                example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
                writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
        writer.close()


    def main():
        create_tf_record("image.tfrecords")
        dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(["image.tfrecords"])
        print(dataset.output_shapes)
```

When I print out the output_shapes, it is empty i.e (). When I checked the .tfrecords file, it is not empty and has a size of 45 MB.

Can somebody please point out the reason why the dataset is empty?

Answer (score 0):

TFRecordDataset creation happens without looking at the filesystem. Each tfrecord file is a list of strings, so the shape of its dataset is scalar. You need to add the dataset parsing ops (to deserialize the example, etc) and manually set the shapes.